# Some sounds coming through wrong output

Tags: sound, speakers, headset, output

I'm not sure why but today some videos are playing through my monitor's speakers even when the Device Output is set to my Headset in settings. Youtube/Twitch in my browser plays through my Headset but if I click play on a embedded youtube video on discord or open a video file I have saved with VLC the sound comes through my speakers. This started happening today.

In sound settings my only output is set to "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - G432 Gaming Headset"

I tried installing pavucontrol and it shows only the Headset is selected. When I play a video with VLC its showing like the sound is coming through the headset in pavucontrol but its still coming out through the speakers. Restarted PC, no change.

I do dual boot with windows 10 and earlier today I did login and update windows for the first time in a couple weeks. I don't know if thats what messed me up.

OS: Ubuntu 21.04 Gnome

KERNEL: 5.12.13-xanmod1

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8-Core

GPU: NVIDIA NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080

GPU DRIVER: NVIDIA 465.27

RAM: 32 GB

Headset: Logitech G432

Monitor: ASUS MG278Q WQHD

EDIT: FIXED! For anyone who encounters a problem like this, I managed to fix it by going into PulseAudio volume control 'Configuration' and setting 'HDA NVIDIA' Profile to Off.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who encounters a problem like this, I managed to fix it by going into PulseAudio volume control 'Configuration' and setting 'HDA NVIDIA' Profile to Off. That was causing come apps to use speakers rather than my headset. Hopes this helps someone else in the future!